# Using preg_replace(), how to only replace matched text if it is shorter than 10 characters?

Tags: php, regex, string, preg-replace

```
$str = "(search: kewyord)";
$str = preg_replace("'\(search: (.*)\)'Ui","(search: <a href=\"search.php?q=\\1\"><b>\\1</b></a>)",$str);
//result->>
$str =  (search: <a href=\"search.php?q=keyword\">kewyord</a>)
```

I wanna change as

if keyword is more than 10 characters, don't replace it.

how can I do that? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To make it match a minimum length you can replace the `*` with a numeric quantifier `{10,}`. But you wanted to opposite, so this would do:

```
 preg_replace("'\(search: (.{1,9})\)'Ui",
```

See http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html under *Limiting Repetition*.

Answer (score 2):

Please don't use the 'U' modifier! (it is bad style, never necessary and serves only to confuse). Instead, apply the universal ? lazy modifier to any quantifiers you wish to be lazy. The dot is also rarely needed. This is probably what you're after:

`'/\(search:\s+([^)\s]{1,9})\)/i'`

Answer (score 1):

You can use `preg_match` with your regex, then use `strlen()` function on matched string.

If matched string's length > 10 then use `str_replace` with matched string as a first param.